# Default value for prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

In order to keep it clean and simple, I've removed the complexity/irrelevant code from the examples and also the component who uses **Parent component**. I want to assign default value to the prop so if the value for the "myText" prop is not passed down to the parent component, it's child component should get the default value for that prop. I tried using defaultProp, but that doesn't work and getting linting compile time errors, can anyone explain why it's wrong what i'm trying and how can i specify the default value for the "myText" prop and don't get this linting error?

**linting gives this error**

> error Forbidden non-null assertion
> @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion

I know one way where i can do something like the following, but it's not clean as i'd have to do conditional check in the jsx which i want to avoid

```
<Child customPlaceholder={props.myText ? props.myText : DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER} searchText={searchText} />
```

### Parent.tsx file

```
const DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER = "Default placeholder text will be here";

interface IProps {
  myText?: string;
  onTextChange: (text: string) => void;
  isValid: boolean;
  onSearchFocused: (is: boolean) => void;
  searchText: string;
}

type Props = IProps & NavigationInjectedProps;

export const Parent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  return (
      <div>
          <Child
            customPlaceholder={props.myText}
            searchText={searchText}
            // other props
          />
       </div>
  );
};

Parent.defaultProps = {
  myText: DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER
}
```

### Child.tsx file

```
interface IOwnProps {
  customPlaceholder: string;
  // some other props which uses rest of props
}

export const Child: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  return (
      <div>
          <input placeholder={props.customPlaceholder} />
          // Some other jsx
      </div>
  );
};
```

**NOTE:** I cannot change the linting rules and also don't have control over changing the prop types or Parent, Child components architecture as these components live in some other repositories and being used in so many different places, the only change which i can do is to add an optional prop which I've tried as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit you Child.tsx like this

```
<input placeholder={props.customPlaceholder||"Your default value"} />
```

You don't need to change your interface.

Comment: Thanks @RiverTwilight for your response on this, but as i mentioned above this is not what i need, instead i want to assign default value for a prop rather than doing conditional check

Answer (score 0):

### You are being tripped up here with how you are typing your functional components.

Please read [this](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/), specifically **[React.FC<> breaks defaultProps](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/#4.-react.fc%3C%3E-breaks-defaultprops)**. I've also included a helpful recreation of how you can define your functional components should you need it below. I've removed props I do not have access to from the interface.

---

I've replicated your setup as best I can in [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-kqy0c?file=/src/index.tsx)

The `index.tsx` file serves as your `Parent` component and the `child.tsx` file is your Child component. I have declared the `Parent` component as an anonymous functional component like you have. I have also used traditional functional component declaration for the `Child` component.

It was slightly unclear to me whether or not your default prop functions as intended when you disable the ESLint rule.

Comment: Hi @Lachlan, thanks for your response and putting it together in a sandbox, much appreciated! well this works fine but couple things i'd like to clarify here:
1- i think i mentioned in my post that i cannot change/disable the ESLinting rule as it's owned by some other team and i can only consume their package, add props but can't change the configs/linting
2- As this package is being used in so many different places, and the above reason i cannot change the function declaration from "React.FC<>"

Comment: @user212223 1 shouldn't affect this solution I don't believe. I only took out some props so I didnt have to define them in the sandbox. The solution stays the same. removing 2 should throw errors you can manage. The fact is that you will either have to refactor our `React.FC` or never use defaultProps. That's a limitation you've run into. I'd try removing `React.FC` once and see what gets thrown

Comment: so if i remove the default props, then how shall i assign the "DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER" to the prop "myText"  as a default value if the prop is not passed down from the "PARENT" component as i cannot refactor the React.FC